# Node.js Express app.use('/route') run into other route?

Tags: node.js, express

In my application, I have 3 routes that are

```
http://localhost:8080/search
http://localhost:8080/user    
http://localhost:8080/shop
```

I write routes in separated file, in server.js(the file run in the terminal):

```
app.use('/', require('./app/routes/index')(app,io,mongoose));
```

In the index.js:

```
  app.use('/search', require('./searchRouter')(router));
  app.use('/user', require('./user')(router,io,mongoose,app,express));
  app.use('/shop', require('./shop')(router,io,mongoose,app,express));
```

They all have a route like:

```
router.route('/')
.get(function(req, res) {
        res.send('routerRestuarant');
    })

.post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('routerRestuarant');
})

.put(function(req,res){
    res.json({
        msg:"new shop.js router"
    })
});
```

problem:

When I send a request to route '/shop', I found the response come from '/search' and no response come from '/shop', how to fix it?

About pass the **mongoose,app,express** variables

Some part of my code is below:

Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
//var router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
var router = express.Router();
var routeInit = function (app,io,mongoose) {
  //app.use('sessions', require('./sessions')(router));

  app.use('/test', require('./searchRouter')(router));
  app.use('/user', require('./user')(router,io,mongoose,app,express));
  app.use('/shop', require('./shop')(router,io,mongoose,app,express));
  return router;
};

module.exports = routeInit;
```

Shop.js:

```
var routeShop = function (router,io,mongoose,app,express) {
var Shop = require('../models/Shop')(mongoose);

router.route('/createDish')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var dish = req.param('dish', null);
        var shopName = req.param('shopName', null);
        for (var i = 0; i < dish.length; i++) {
            Shop.addDish(shopName, dish[i], function(err) {
                if (null == err)
                    res.json({
                        code: 200
                    });
            })
        }
    })
  return router;
};

module.exports = routeShop;
```

In Shop.js, I need the  variable mongoose to init the mongoose schema, If i am not pass the variable mongoose here, the complier error is:

```
/Users/Documents/Dropbox/MScCS/fos/app/routes/shop.js:8
var Shop = require('../models/Shop')(mongoose);
                                     ^

ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined
    at routeShop (/Users/liyan/Documents/Dropbox/MScCS/fos/food-ordering-by-zwy-liyan/food-ordering/app/routes/shop.js:8:38)
```

Comment: You don't need to pass the `mongoose,app,express` variables to other modules. Node.js caches the loaded modules and you can reference again and again without need to pass.

Comment: I have code related to mongoose,app etc, If I do not pass them, I will get complier error

Comment: You cannot have compiler error, it's interpreting. @MukeshSharma is right, You don't need to pass express, app, mongoose - they are cached, and available as var mongoose = require('mongoose');  *please note that if You've done connection using mongoose - it keeps connection in other files where You do require mongoose.

Comment: I think it's my fault that I can not clearly express it. I'm try to give some code and screen shot

Comment: I have edit my question and post the complier error, I am new to node so I do not know why this happen:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

in server.js:

```
// defining components to be accessible from route handlers
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  req.components = {
    io: io, 
    mongo: mongoose
  };
  next();
});

app.use(require('./app/routes/index'));
```

in index.js:

```
var 
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.use('/search', require('./searchRouter'));
router.use('/user', require('./user'));
router.use('/shop', require('./shop'));

module.exports = router;
```

in router files:

```
var 
  express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  req.components.io.emit('message', {data: "I'm in restaurant"});
  res.send('routerRestuarant');
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('routerRestuarant');
})

router.put('/', function(req,res){
  res.json({
    msg:"new shop.js router"
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I follow your instructions but get an error in index.js: throw new Error(msg);
    ^

Error: Router.use() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]  the error line is :router.use('/search', require('./searchRouter'));

Comment: I gave You part of code, use module.export where it necessary. You're new, but not child, I don't wanna take Your hand and go for a walk through NodeJS

Comment: yes, i correctly follow your code, no complier error now, but now the server do not have response, I will trying to figure it out. Thank you

Comment: updated my answer, added: module.exports = router; in files, cuz it's necessary moment in nodejs if You do require, so You've to somehow return it if You want to use it from calling file. if You'll have exceptions, inform me. today I'm gracious (: